# GPS Chip and GPS Service on Android Phones

Tags: android, gps

Whether I use Google's location services or similar services provided by some third party software, do I still need to manually enable anything by selecting one of the settings options, as shown below?

Settings > Location and Security > My location 
              (Option1) Use wireless networks
              (Option2) Use GPS satellites

Since these days there are many GPS software programs available, what is the role of the onboard GPS chip on an Android phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of the onboard GPS chip is to receive radio signals emitted by the approx. 32 GPS satellites. The data in these signals is used to calculate the geographical position of the device on earth. Such a position includes at least: time, latitude and longitude.
Without such a chip the device cannot determine its accurate position. That is the role of the chip.

The role of (GPS) applications is to use these positions and do something with that, e.g display your current position on a (google) map.